# Tough Probability Question.

Tags: probability

Box 1 and Box 2 exist. Box 1 contains 4 red balls and 1 blue ball. Box 2 contains 5 blue balls and 3 red balls. Draw from box one first. The next box drawn from is determined by the color of the ball drawn. A red ball will lead you to draw from Box 1, while a blue ball will lead you to draw from box 2. What is the chance a red ball is drawn on the 100th draw?

Comment: Have you heard of Markov chains?

Comment: I wasnt aware of them, but now that I have educated myself on the matter, how can i form such a recursive formula if thats even what I should be doing?

Comment: Isaac's answer is probably the way to go

Answer (score 1):

I assume we draw with replacement, since otherwise there would not be 100 draws.

Anyways, to solve this question, we will need to use something called a matrix. If you don't know what that is, watch a Khan Academy video or something. Pay special attention to how matrices are multiplied, as that is important to constructing something called the transition matrix.
$$
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} \\
   a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$
Here is a transition matrix, where Entry $a_{i,j}$, is the chance that something in state $i$ will move to state $j$ in the next step. We can iterate this transition matrix by multiplying it by itself, and we can iterate it $n$ times by raising it to the $n$th power.

So, in our case, our starting position is the vector $[1,0]$ since we start with a $100$% chance that we are picking from the first box. And our transition matrix is

$$
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   4/5 & 1/5 \\
   3/8 & 5/8 \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$$

So now we have all the tools we need, and we perform the following computation (preferably on a calculator).
$$
[1,0]\cdot
\left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   4/5 & 1/5 \\
   3/8 & 5/8 \\
  \end{array} } \right]^{100}
\approx [.6522, .3478]
$$
Thus, our chance of just having picked the red ball last time is simply the chance of us being in the first state. Thus, the probability is $\approx65.22$%.

It may be interesting to note that a matrix to the n power seems to converge to a limiting transition matrix as n goes to infinity. I suggest you investigate this further, as it is probably what this problem would be leading up to.